# IntelliJ Out Of Memory Error while compiling a big WAR

Tags: java, intellij-idea

A quick question here. I'm compiling a fairly big WAR in `IntelliJ 2016.1.1` with `Java 8`. I'm using a Tomcat plugin in Ultimate edition. Everything runs on 64 bit Windows 8 machine.

I'm getting `java.lang.OutOfMemory error: GC overhead limit exceeded
I've increased the Xmx/Xms parameters in idea64.exe`.vmoptions Now it looks like:

```
-Xmx4096m 
-Xms1024m 
-XX:MaxPermSize=350m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=240m
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50
-ea
-Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
-XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow
```

But it seems like its in Java compiler itself, so apparently it didn't help Somehow I can't find the correct way to declare that.
I'd appreciate if someone could show me how to do that correctly.

Thanks and have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

See if this link helps you:
[What are the Xms and Xmx parameters when starting JVMs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14763079/what-are-the-xms-and-xmx-parameters-when-starting-jvms)

It might cause of a bug which is causing your program to do runaway memory allocation, which will always be resulting in out-of-memory errors no matter how much you increase your heap size. In that case, you will need to look at your code, not at your project options.

Comment: thanks, however I'm looking for an answer how to specify these parameters in the last intelliJ version while compiling a WAR file. IntelliJ runs javac internally so stating in general what Xms and Xmx are doesn't really help. Also I'm only compiling my program and don't run it so tomcat doesn't even start. Thanks in any case